# sql select - another select with NULL returns only NULL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a like the one below that does a minus from another select. The problem I have is that if the second SELECT (the one to do minus with) returns NULL, the full query returns NULL even if the first query has values. Seems like MySQL thinks `1-NULL`=`NULL`. How can I fix this?

```
SELECT round(sum(iv.`amount`)) - 
(
 SELECT round(sum(pay.`amount`)) amountSum

     FROM invoice iv
    LEFT JOIN invoiceFactoring ivf on ivf.invoiceID=iv.invoiceID 
    LEFT JOIN user systemuser ON (systemuser.userID=iv.ownerUserID)
    LEFT JOIN Payment pay ON (pay.`invoiceID`=iv.`invoiceID`)
     WHERE 
        (iv.invoiceStateID = 2 OR iv.invoiceStateID = 3) 
     AND 
    (ivf.`invoiceFactoringProcessID` = 7)
     AND     (pay.`paymentMethodID` = 1 OR pay.`paymentMethodID` = 2)
     AND systemuser.`groupID` = 1 
     AND iv.`disabled` <> 1 
     AND ivf.`invoiceExpiryDate` BETWEEN date_add(now(), INTERVAL - 28 DAY) AND date_add(now(), INTERVAL - 21 DAY)

)
    FROM invoice iv
    LEFT JOIN invoiceFactoring ivf on ivf.invoiceID=iv.invoiceID 
        LEFT JOIN user systemuser ON (systemuser.userID=iv.ownerUserID)
    WHERE 
    (iv.invoiceStateID = 2 OR iv.invoiceStateID = 3)
        AND 
    (ivf.`invoiceFactoringProcessID` = 7 or ivf.`invoiceFactoringProcessID`)
    AND systemuser.`groupID` = 1 
    AND iv.`disabled` <> 1   /* ta bort de som är inaktiva*/    
    AND ivf.`invoiceExpiryDate` BETWEEN date_add(now(), INTERVAL - 28 DAY) AND date_add(now(), INTERVAL - 21 DAY)
```

Comment: That's not just MySQL - That's not even just SQL - That's how NULL is defined to behave - period.

Comment: @Dems: see how `1-0=0` can be considered a universal truth but I don't think the same can be said of `1-NULL=NULL`. Rather, it is something defined** by the SQL Standard and implemented by mySQL. ** I mean that loosely!

Comment: @onedaywhen - Except that NULL isn't a purely SQL concept.  It's since transcended that.

Comment: @Dems: do you have a citation for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

perhaps you can wrap the "inner" sql with an IFNULL

```
SELECT round(sum(iv.`amount`)) - 
IFNULL((
 SELECT round(sum(pay.`amount`)) amountSum
 FROM invoice iv
 LEFT JOIN invoiceFactoring ivf on ivf.invoiceID=iv.invoiceID 
 LEFT JOIN user systemuser ON (systemuser.userID=iv.ownerUserID)
 LEFT JOIN Payment pay ON (pay.`invoiceID`=iv.`invoiceID`)
 WHERE 
    (iv.invoiceStateID = 2 OR iv.invoiceStateID = 3) 
 AND 
    (ivf.`invoiceFactoringProcessID` = 7)
 AND     (pay.`paymentMethodID` = 1 OR pay.`paymentMethodID` = 2)
 AND systemuser.`groupID` = 1 
 AND iv.`disabled` <> 1 
 AND ivf.`invoiceExpiryDate` BETWEEN date_add(now(), INTERVAL - 28 DAY) 
 AND date_add(now(), INTERVAL - 21 DAY)
),0)

FROM invoice iv
LEFT JOIN invoiceFactoring ivf on ivf.invoiceID=iv.invoiceID 
    LEFT JOIN user systemuser ON (systemuser.userID=iv.ownerUserID)
WHERE 
(iv.invoiceStateID = 2 OR iv.invoiceStateID = 3)
    AND 
(ivf.`invoiceFactoringProcessID` = 7 or ivf.`invoiceFactoringProcessID`)
AND systemuser.`groupID` = 1 
AND iv.`disabled` <> 1   /* ta bort de som är inaktiva*/    
AND ivf.`invoiceExpiryDate` BETWEEN date_add(now(), INTERVAL - 28 DAY) AND date_add(now(), INTERVAL - 21 DAY)
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing anything with a null returns null. You need to define what you want to happen if it is null using COALESCE or IFNULL.
Check http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_isnull.asp for an example.

Comment: "Doing anything with a null returns null" -- `NULL IS NULL` evaluates to TRUE.

Answer (score 0):

> Seems like MySQL thinks `1-NULL=NULL`.

Yes; and it is correct. "One" minus "unknown" is "unknown". If you want the second subquery's `NULL` to be treated as `0`, then you need to wrap it in a call to [the `COALESCE` operator](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce): change `(SELECT ...)` to `COALESCE((SELECT ...), 0)`.